# Create a pull request to a public repo from the front end

Tags: github, pull-request

I'm struggling to find out how I can achieve the following (I'm aware it's dumb but I have no choice):

Assume there's a public repository with a shopping list in it

```
shopping_list.txt
```

I would like to have an input box (in a react application) for additional shopping list items and then a user can submit and the new items will be added the end of `shopping_list.txt` in a pull request.

I'm having a lot of trouble identifying if this is even possible from the front end or if this is something that needs to be handled from a backend.

Comment: So you want an automated system to generate a git branch, make git commits with changes to that file, push it to some repository, and create a pull request from that branch whenever the user submits that form? You will need some kind of webserver backend for that. A nodejs or spring app could do it.

Comment: @Derek Yes that's correct. Interesting I will look into trying it out with Nodejs, I assume it's not possible to do on the frontend then?

Comment: It might be technically possible, but probably not a great idea. If auth is required at all, which is likely the case, then it's probably not possible.